# how webpack replace a string in .ts file?

Tags: javascript, angular, plugins, webpack

I have a angular 2 project originally used to bundle works with systemjs.

now  i want  use  webpack to bundle  this  project.

But the original code has a lot of such a string. such as

I want to replace all the strings with the absolute directory where the files are located.The original time, prod mode or dev mode, this string will be replaced with a path string.

Now I would like to use a webpack to replace this string before a .ts file is compiled. What kind of plugin should I use?

for example:
login.module.routing.ts

{ path: 'login', /app/src/login#LoginModule },

I want  replace    before  use  webpack  compile.

such as : { path: 'login', /root/myproject/app/src/login#LoginModule },

thanks  very  much  !

Answer (score 11):

For this requirement you can use [string-replace-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-webpack-plugin).

Usage Example:

```
var StringReplacePlugin = require("string-replace-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
   module: {
      loaders: [
         // configure replacements for file patterns 
         { 
            test: /index.html$/,
            loader: StringReplacePlugin.replace({
                replacements: [
                    {
                        pattern: /<!-- @secret (\w*?) -->/ig,
                        replacement: function (match, p1, offset, string) {
                            return secrets.web[p1];
                        }
                    }
                ]})
            }
      ]
   },
   plugins: [
      // an instance of the plugin must be present 
      new StringReplacePlugin()
   ]
}
```

I hope this helps to solve your problem.

Comment: Great, probably you can do an upvote and mark it as correct answer, this would help other users to see if the solutions works or not. Have a great day.

Comment: sorry   , when  i do an upvote  ,it  said  : thanks for the feedback!  votes cast bu those with less than 15 reputation are recorded,but do not change the publicly displayed post score